# How to sort a column of numerical values within a table from a csv file, by highest to lowest value?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a table of information with two columns; 'Name' and 'Score /10', stored in a csv file. The cvs file is named 'Year 1 List'. Currently I can sort the table alphabetically, based on the 'Name' column, so that each name will be output with their corresponding score in alphabetical order. Now, I want to be able to sort the table based on the 'Score /10' column, by the highest score first and lowest score last. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Do I have to convert the 'Score /10' column into a list? My code is as follows:

```
print ("Do you wish to view previous class' results?")
option = input()

if option == ("yes"):
    print ("Which class' results' do you wish to view; 1,2 or 3?")
    viewyear = int(input())

    if viewyear == 1:
        print ("How do you want to view your results; alpha - alphabetically by name, av - mean score, desc - from highest to lowest?.")
        viewoption = input()
        if viewoption == ('alpha'):
                with open("Year 1 List.csv", "r") as f:
                    for line in sorted(f):
                        print(line)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
print next(f) # skip the header we dont want that
for line in sorted(f,key=lambda line:float(line.split(",")[1])):
```

of coarse pandas would make this even easier

```
df = pd.Dataframe.from_csv("my.csv")
print df.sort("Score /10")
```

for the last bit of help here it is in an interpreter (instead of `f=open("somefile")` we use `s=cStringIO.StringIO("""...""")`, as this lets us "include" our csv data in the example)

```
>>> s = cStringIO.StringIO("""StudentName, Score/10
... bob,12
... sue,6
... billy,18
... sam,9
... """)
>>> print next(s) #the header
StudentName, Score/10

>>> for line in sorted(s,key=lambda line:float(line.split(",")[1])): #the rest
...     print line
...
sue,6

sam,9

bob,12

billy,18
```

Comment: when 'line' was printed it brought back an error : "for line in sorted(f,key=lambda line:float(line.split(",")[1])):
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Score /10\n'" When I took out 'float' and it output the data from lowest to highest, and a score of '10' would be counted as '1' in the order from lowest to highest. How can i change this to be a) highest to lowest b) ranked with 10 as the highest score? @joran

Comment: I did not realize the file had the header text in it ... I assumed that all the values in the 2nd column were floats

Comment: 'print next(f)'? what do you mean by this?  This doesn't skip the header of the 2nd column. Currently this goes to the 2nd column header, but still includes it when trying to convert it to from string to float - how can i skip this header? 'print next(f)' won't work. Thanks

Comment: that should skip the first row of the file ... so that when you continue you are only looking at the data not the headers

Comment: forgive me as I'm fairly new to this - this still brings up an invalid syntax @joran `elif viewoption == ('desc'):
            with open('Year 1 List.csv') as f:
                print next(f) # skip the header we dont want that
                for line in sorted(f,key=lambda line:float(line.split(",")[1])):
                    print (line)` is the code

Comment: can you help? @joran

Comment: how can i skip the first header? 'print next (f)' won't work. also i have removed all text from the headers to make it easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy from Python.
You read the csv file by :

```
import numpy

reading = numpy.genfromtxt("filename", delimiter = " ")
sort = numpy.max("column")
print sort
```

Comment: I'd rather use regular python modules as not all my colleagues have the Numpy module installed. Can you write this using pre-installed modules? @astrolabe1993

Comment: You just need to write : import numpy. I think that it's the better solution to solve your problem

Comment: i have tried that and it returns 'ImportError: No module named 'numpy''